# I'm getting an error when installing Vue.js 3 on Chrome OS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, npm-init, code-server, crostini

I'm trying to use Vue.js 3 on Chrome OS (64-bit, v99) using [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server), using the official [Vue installation guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools), but when I run `npm init vue@latest` I get the following error:

```
user@penguin ~/vue-project> npm init vue@latest
/home/user/.npm/_npx/2f7e7bff16d1c534/node_modules/create-vue/outfile.cjs:5894
  const userAgent = process.env.npm_config_user_agent ?? "";
                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/user/vue-project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-vue

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2022-03-11T20_09_26_156Z-debug.log
user@penguin ~/vue-project [1]>
```

Comment: Hey! What node version are you using? You can find it out via `node -v` in your terminal.

Comment: Hello, I'm currenly using v12.22.5.

Answer (score 0):

The error points to `??`, which is the [nullish coallescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Support for that operator was [added in Node 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility), but you're using Node 12 (based on your comment).

The solution is to upgrade your Node version to Node 14 or newer.